# How to define custom float-type numpy dtypes (C-API)

Tags: c++, python, numpy, boost-python

I have a custom float data type that emulates 128bit floats using two 64bit floats (the double-double class `dd_real` from the [QD library](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/)). From C++ I want to export an ndarray to python. I already know how to do this for 64bit floats, but  for double-doubles I somehow need to specify my own custom dtype. How to do that?

Note: numpy has its own 128bit float (np.float128) unfortunately this maps to `long double` in C/C++ which is merely an 80bit-float stored in 128bit (on all of my platforms).

In fact, one should be able to do this exactly in the same way that numpy exports np.float128 (I just don't know how that is done), with the only difference that it uses `dd_real` on the C++ side instead of `long double`.

If this helps, I already exported the C++ type `dd_real` to python using `boost::python` maybe this can be reused somehow.

---

So far I was able to research the following

1. The numpy documentation for [dtypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#defining-new-types) refers to  [C-API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.dtype.html) for how to export custom dtypes, but that document somehow only explains the existing dtypes not how to create new ones.
2. When [browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199218/how-to-create-a-custom-numpy-dtype-using-cython) stackoverflow I found [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-dtypes/blob/master/npytypes/quaternion/numpy_quaternion.c) example, but I wonder if for `dd_real` this could be simpler. I also don't see where the dtype is actually generated. Maybe only in python [__ init__](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-dtypes/blob/master/npytypes/quaternion/__init__.py) via `np.typeDict['quaternion'] = np.dtype(quaternion)`. How to use that dtype in C++ when I want to generate an ndarray?

Answer (score 4):

The repository you linked to,

```
https://github.com/numpy/numpy-dtypes
```

probably contains the simplest possible examples on how to add new dtype to Numpy. I'm not aware of an easier way. Note the calls to `register_cast_function` and `REGISTER_UFUNC` in these files: these tell Numpy how operations such as multiplication and casting should be dealt with on an element-by-element level.

However, if what you actually want to do is to only export your data, you could just export as an array of doubles, or maybe bundling two doubles to a single data type

```
np.dtype([('a', double), ('b', double)])
```

Then, you'd need to write separate functions to do operations on these arrays (as `arr1 * arr2` won't do what you want here). One possible way to go further and make also `arr1 * arr2` to work would be to subclass `np.ndarray` your data type, overriding `__mul__` etc operations.

Comment: what is the equivalent of `np.dtype(...)` in C++?

Comment: Construct the list with the tuples, and call `PyArray_DescrConverter`. But it's probably easier to just export an array of doubles and do that on the Python side.

Comment: Well I need to construct an ndarray from C++ and for that I need the dtype in C++.