# Define a new numpy type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, int

I would like to define a custom `numpy` array data type : for some (audio) applications, a `np.int24` data type could be useful. A few remarks :

- of course I could use `np.int32` instead and forget about the lost memory space
- or I may use some other tricks for seeing an array as a `np.int8` array, and grouping them by 3, but this would involve dirty coding...

... But when using gigabytes of data, the best solution (instead of wasting 1/4 th of a `np.int32`) would be to define a new `dtype = np.int24`.

**Is there a documentation showing how to do that properly ?**

*Remark : `24 bit` audio is very common in professionnal audio applications, and when dealing with gigabytes of data, using 24 bits array would be very useful.*

Comment: yes but it fits in an integer number of times a *byte*, so it could be okay, don't you think so @ramcdougal ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define custom float-type numpy dtypes (C-API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659019/how-to-define-custom-float-type-numpy-dtypes-c-api)