# using numpy arrays with complex dtypes in cython

Tags: numpy, cython

I have a numpy array with dtype

```
dtype([('pos', '<f8', (3,)), ('vel', '<f8', (3,)), ('mass', '<f8'), ('deps', 'i1', (16,))], align=True)
```

And want to use this with cython code. However, all the docs I can find seem only to work for simple dtypes - int/float, not a structure like this.

How can I specify this type when passing this array into a function?

```
def fname(np.ndarray[TYPE??, ndim=1] obj):
```

Or should just workaround this by casting to a 2d array of doubles

Comment: Solution can be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199218/how-to-create-a-custom-numpy-dtype-using-cython?rq=1

Comment: I've flagged to close it as a duplicate so it's linked by the "official" mechanism. Thanks for pointing out the link when you found it!